# How to restore Tensorflow-Slim pre-trained models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-slim

Using `Tensorflow 1.3` [slim models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim), we have access to many pre-trained models. Normally they come in three. For example for MobileNet:

```
67903136 Jun 14 00:15 mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
19954 Jun 14 00:15 mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.ckpt.index
4319476 Jun 14 00:15 mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.ckpt.meta
```

Apparently, the traditional method of accessing the weights is not working:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("path/your/meta/file")
saver.restore("path/to/data/file")

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("path/to/write/graph")
writer.add_graph(graph)
```

This will give an error:

```
ValueError: No op named SSTableReaderV2 in defined operations.
```

Using the backend class `Event_accumulator` will only return empty arrays:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing.event_accumulator import EventAccumulator
event_acc = EventAccumulator('${CHKPNT_DIR}')
event_acc.Reload()

# Show all tags in the log file
print(event_acc.Tags())
```

Is there any way to workaround this problem to see the weights? 
I have seen people trying to use the Slim-git to make [frozen models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1564) (`.pb`), but the output .pb file's Scalars returns empty when read by `tensorboard` either.